# Play(Scala) Framework 2.4.x - Form validations to validate equality of two fields in the same form at field-level

Tags: scala, playframework

My application makes use of Play-2.4.2/Scala-2.11.6 
I use PlayForms+HTML+Bootstrap to customize my views for **User Registration module**.

The form validation is a server-side validation , and I make use of ScalaCustomValidation to perform this.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCustomValidations

Below is an example of ScalaCustomValidation provided by the play docs.

```
val allNumbers = """\d*""".r
val allLetters = """[A-Za-z]*""".r

val passwordCheckConstraint: Constraint[String] = Constraint("constraints.passwordcheck")({
  plainText =>
    val errors = plainText match {
      case allNumbers() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))
      case allLetters() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))
      case _ => Nil
    }
    if (errors.isEmpty) {
      Valid
    } else {
      Invalid(errors)
    }
})
```

Now this validation can be called on the user form as below

```
val userFormConstraintsAdHoc = Form(
  mapping(
    "username" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 12).verifying(passwordCheckConstraint),
   "confirmpassword" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 12).verifying(passwordCheckConstraint)
  )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply) 
)
```

This works fine and validates the strength constraint for both  password and confirmPassword fields.
Now I need to define a constraint to validate the **equality of password and confirmPassword** .

Can someone help me on how to write this particular type of  constraint , that actually reads the values of two(or more) fields of the same form and performs some the validation over the values of those fields

**NOTE** : I **do not** want to add the constraint at the case class level , I want to add it at field level only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fact that you need information from more than one field prevents you from using a field-level constraint since they're supposed to be *composable pure functions* that don't have access to external state. You could use a `Forms.tuple` field for the password and confirmation and validate that separately, but I'm not sure what advantage that would confer over a form-level constraint:

```
val userFormConstraintsAdHoc = Form(
  mapping(
    "username" -> nonEmptyText,
    "passwords" -> Forms.tuple(
      "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 12),
      "confirm" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 12)
    ).verifying("constraints.passwords.match", 
       passConfirm => passConfirm._1 == passConfirm._2)
  )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply) 
)
```

Comment: I agree, I think that a validation involving two or more fields needs to be done outside the single fields validation part.